# How to configure one-to-many and nullable one-to-one relation together on 2 entities by entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want configure the following models in EF.

- **Many offers can related to one Request**
- **Each Request should related to one Request**
- **One offer maybe accepted**

Models:

```
public class Request 
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     // Nullable Foreign Key
     public Guid? AcceptedOfferId { get; set; }    
     public Offer AcceptedOffer { get; set; }
     
     public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     public Guid RequestId { get; set; }    
     public Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

How should I configure it?

Following configuration give me this error:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Request.Offers' and
> 'Offer.Request', because there already is a relationship between
> 'Request.AcceptedOffer' and 'Offer.Request'. Navigation properties can
> only participate in a single relationship.

```
public class Request: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.Request>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entities.Request> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        builder.HasOne(p => p.AcceptedOffer)
            .WithOne(p => p.Request)
            .HasForeignKey("Request", "AcceptedOfferId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);  
    }
}

public class Offer: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.Offer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entities.Offer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Request).WithMany(p => p.Offers).HasForeignKey(p => p.RequestId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);           
                
    }
}
```

Comment: You swapped the method bodies of the config classes.

Comment: @GertArnold, Yes, I have been mistaken in writing the question but the problem has not solved yet. How should I configure it?

Comment: I think "Each Request should related to one Request" is also a typo. From your model it seems that each Offer should be related to one Request and vv.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use `Offer.Request` as the *inverse property* (the property on the other end of the relationship) of both `Request.AcceptedOffer` and `Request.Offers`.

The first thing is to add a second `Request` property to `Offer`:

```cs
public class Offer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public Request RequestAcceptedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the configuration (I change the config class names for clarity):

```cs
public class RequestConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Request>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Request> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        builder.HasOne(p => p.AcceptedOffer)
            .WithOne(o => o.RequestAcceptedBy)
            .HasForeignKey<Request>(r => r.AcceptedOfferId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}

public class OfferConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Offer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Offer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Request)
            .WithMany(p => p.Offers)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RequestId);
    }
}
```